# Salesforce Platform API Versions Retirement of Versions 21.0 through 30.0

Tags: api-version

Do you have a list of components to be verified for "Retirement of Versions 21.0 through 30.0":

1. How do we can make sure that no managed package would be impacted with this change?
2. If any apex code contains HTTP Get calls like '/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account', it would be impacted?
3. API version of metadata like APEX classes, LWC , aura and VF pages would be impacted with this change?

Few areas where this retirement can impact, which I can think of is:

1. Ajax calls from VF pages using connection.js.
2. Connection.js calls from javascript buttons.

Could you please let me know if you already have a list of items to be checked other than above 2?

Comment: If you mean [this change](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389618&type=1) you can see this only applies to APIs (REST, SOAP and Bulk). You need to check your API client code to see if it includes use of API versions below 31. Whether any managed packages you use have code that calls platform APIs is something to ask each package vendor; they are responsible for fixing this. Note that packages that use such APIs directly should be relatively unusual and do things like multi-org data transfer etc.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks, Yes I am talking about the same change. But, if any code using standard API calls like  '/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account' from apex code, will it be impacted?. Same with ajax calls using connection.js from JavaScript buttons or VF pages. Our org does not have any external integrations now.

Comment: @PhilW Basically if we do not have any active external integrations in our org, do we need to check anything other than ajax calls from vf pages and javascript buttons using connection.js and standard API calls(like /services/data/) from apex code ?

Comment: Yes, if the REST API URL includes a version before 31 this is impacted. One option to help you with your specific org's metadata would be to retrieve it all (e.g. using `sfdx force:source:pull`) then search through for text like `/([12][0-9]|30)\.0` (regex).

Comment: This will not find usages in managed packages; you need to ask the vendors as mentioned before.

Comment: @PhilW As per salesforce documentation, 
This retirement does not include the following:
Custom Apex REST & SOAP Web Services, Apex Classes, Apex Triggers, or Visualforce Pages*.
Affected managed package versions that are pointing to metadata content less than or equal to version 30.0. In that case managed packages would be impacted?

Comment: The way I read that is that this change does not affect any metadata item versions, just the APIs. So a package can include any metadata with a version in this range and not be impacted. However, I could have misinterpreted this badly phrased bullet point.

Comment: @PhilW Are you saying API versions of metadata like apex classes is not impacted with this retirement(which we can see under version settings tab of apex class), but will be impacted if those classes contains any calls to old version API's like '/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account'

Comment: I am saying that it is the REST API version that counts, and not the Apex class "API version". So, yes.